"This" and "That" situation
I want to make a album named "This Doesn't Mean Anything" but I don't know if I should use "That" or "This", it's this correct?

Either will do. Your choice.

Both are standard English. "This" refers to something close to hand, "That" refers to something more distant. "This" might be what I'm saying now, "that" might be what [s]he just said. Which you choose is an artistic choice depending on the meaning you want to convey.
